# need assistance to install Epson L380 printer drivers on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, xubuntu

I just installed Ubuntu 16.04 and want to install Epson L380 printer but I don’t have the drivers.
Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The epson printer driver is available here:

http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/du/02/DriverDownloadInfo.do?LG2=EN&CN2=&DSCMI=55539&DSCCHK=5ef6ec128765534a989152269045f12fc58077f2